# Ms access and vb.net

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

We have a access database(.mdb), two windows applications are using it at a same time, which is working fine. Now i am writting another windows appliction (as I dont have permission to alter existing applications) and connecting to the same access database. But I am getting error msg:

> Could not use ','; file already in use

My connection String

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Program Files\Filenet\Capture\Reports\Statistics.mdb" (in App.config file)

public static string Access_connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Access_conn"];   ( declared in a class)
using (var Access_conn = new OleDbConnection(Class_conn_string.Access_connStr))
{
  //// Connecting to db
}
```

Can anybody help to resolve this issue. 
I searcherd other similar posts, which says user needs to have read/write permission for the folder but user already have that permission.

```
Operation must use an updatable query
```

is totally different from

```
Could not use ','; file already in use
```

Giving folder read/write permission resolves the updateble query issue. But my problem needs to be solved without giving permission.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720346/c-sharp-access-database-in-use-or-permission-failure

Comment: this is not vb .net. It´s c#.

Comment: 1. Try to run the application with admin priviledges.
2. First try with no other application accessing database and try. If that works, your code is fine.

Post your results.

Comment: @Alex B Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Mahadev 1)With admin privileges in my system its working file. It is not working in user system where the user cant have admin privileges. 2)With other 2 applications closed this is working fine. But how do I make it work without admin privileges and both applications running. Is it even possible????

Comment: Using `Program Files` for storing data is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Sunil : I don't think its possible using MS-Access.